# Same math and numpy functions don't give the same result when applied to pixels values

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to calculate the *Perceived brightness* ,based on the formula from this [link](http://alienryderflex.com/hsp.html), of this image:

[image]

The idea is to loop over each pixel and calculate its *Perceived brightness* according to this formula:

**Pb = sqrt(0.241 R² + 0.691 G² + 0.068 B²)**

then sum all the values and calculate the mean.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
import cv2
from math import sqrt

img = cv2.imread('e.png')
H, W = img.shape[:2]
pr = 0.241
pg = 0.691
pb = 0.068

p = []
for h in range(0, H):
    for w in range(0, W):
        p.append(sqrt(pr * pow(img[h][w][2], 2) + pg * pow(img[h][w][1], 2) + pb * pow(img[h][w][0], 2)))
arr = np.reshape(p, (H, W))
cv2.imwrite('loop_img.jpg', arr)
print(np.mean(arr))
```

The image I got at the end is this:

[image]
And the mean is **82.04557421656007**

However when I repeated the same process using numpy (to avoid looping over each pixel), I got different values!
Here is the code I used:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('e.png')
b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
pr = 0.241
pg = 0.691
pb = 0.068
P = np.sqrt(pr * pow(r, 2) + pg * pow(g, 2) + pb * pow(b, 2))
cv2.imwrite('np_img.jpg', P)
print(np.mean(P))
```

The image I got is this:

[image]
And the mean is **1.6438602314083277**

The most weird is that when I applied the same methods on a random numpy array, I got similar results!

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

from math import sqrt

pr = 0.241
pg = 0.691
pb = 0.068

arr = np.array([[[255, 127,   0],
                 [255, 127,   0]],

                [[255, 133,   0],
                [255, 133,   0]],

                [[255, 138,   0],
                [255, 138,   0]]])

b, g, r = cv2.split(arr)

p = []
for h in range(0, 3):
    for w in range(0, 2):
        print(arr[h][w])
        p.append(sqrt(pr * pow(arr[h][w][2], 2) + pg * pow(arr[h][w][1], 2) + pb * pow(arr[h][w][0], 2)))
arr_p = np.reshape(p, (3, 2))
print('arr_p:', arr_p)
np_p = np.sqrt(pr * pow(r, 2) + pg * pow(g, 2) + pb * pow(b, 2))
print('np_ap:', np_p)
print('loop_mean:', np.mean(arr_p))
print('numpy_mean:', np.mean(np_p))
```

The results I got:

```
arr_p: [[124.7671391  124.7671391 ]
 [129.01472397 129.01472397]
 [132.59375551 132.59375551]]  

np_ap: [[124.7671391  124.7671391 ]
 [129.01472397 129.01472397]
 [132.59375551 132.59375551]]  

loop_mean: 128.79187285939827  

numpy_mean: 128.79187285939827
```

Is there any explanation why I got different results with the image and similar results with the second array? (could it be related to the array elements type?)
**N.B:**  I use

```
python==3.6
numpy==1.16.1  
opencv-contrib-python==4.0.0.21  
opencv-python==4.0.0.21
```

Comment: What are the data types for `b` from `b, g, r = cv2.split(img)` and `b = img[:,:,0]` ?

Comment: @Joe, the problem is solved by using `np.float_power` instead of `pow`. The problem is related to data type as I thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `pow` function to a `np.uint8` array. First, lets have a simple example:

```
>> a = np.arange(20, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(4,5)
```

which gives:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]], dtype=uint8)
```

It is important to test with np.uint8 which is the type of a loaded image. Then we do pow or np.power (they behave exactly the same) and the result is the following:

```
>> np.power(a,2)
array([[  0,   1,   4,   9,  16],
       [ 25,  36,  49,  64,  81],
       [100, 121, 144, 169, 196],
       [225,   0,  33,  68, 105]], dtype=uint8)

>> pow(a,2)
array([[  0,   1,   4,   9,  16],
       [ 25,  36,  49,  64,  81],
       [100, 121, 144, 169, 196],
       [225,   0,  33,  68, 105]], dtype=uint8)
```

As you can see, the power function did not change the type... and  this leads to overflow...

You have 2 options to solve it:

Cast the type and then cast it back like

```
b = np.float32(b) #same for g and r or to the whole image
# or this
b, g, r = cv2.split(np.float32(img))
```

and then before saving use `np.uint8()`, opencv saving functions usually work only with uint8... maybe the newer versions doesn't.

The other thing is to use `np.float_power` which will return float32 type and the correct numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is due to the difference of data type conversion rules between numpy `array` and raw data types.

In the case of numpy array, the calculation is being done as follows:

```
P = np.sqrt(pr * pow(r, 2) + pg * pow(g, 2) + pb * pow(b, 2))
```

The culprit operation here is `pow`. Since the default data type of image read using `cv2.imread` is `np.uint8` so consequently, `r`, `g` and `b` also have the same type. Now, when `pow` function is applied on the numpy array, the resultant array tends to have the same integer type. The values in the result are truncated to the range of `uint8` type thus causing invalid results. Since the results are truncated, the mean value becomes very small as being observed.

## Possible solutions:

**1. Convert input image to floating point type:**

```
img = cv2.imread('e.png')
img = img.astype(np.float)
```

**2. Use floating point operands in `pow`:**

```
P = np.sqrt(pr * pow(r, 2.0) + pg * pow(g, 2.0) + pb * pow(b, 2.0))
```

## Why are the results correct in the loop case?

```
p.append(sqrt(pr * pow(img[h][w][2], 2) + pg * pow(img[h][w][1], 2) + pb * pow(img[h][w][0], 2)))
```

Apparently, applying `pow` on a single integer instead of numpy `array` results in a value of larger integer type (`int64`) thus avoiding the issue of truncation.